# Store and display a selection of nodes

Tags: 7

I would like to be able make a selection of nodes. The chosen nodes could be displayed in a block or similar. Much like a cart. Then I want to be able to save the selection and get a link for it that I can send and view. Could be either for 7 or 8.

Comment: What do you want displayed in that link? A list of all the nodes? and/or the field values in those nodes?

Comment: Your question is really broad. This is the kind of things you could achieve with the module flag for the selection and a views set of displays for blocks and or pages

Comment: Yes, a list of the selected nodes with links to the actual pages and preferably also fields of these nodes. Could be a view.